# java - Thread.sleep

Tags: java, multithreading

In the code and output below, t2 doesn't start until t1 finishes. Shouldn't they work parallel? Is Thread.sleep() affect whole process?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        T t1 = new T(), t2 = new T();

        t1.run();
        t2.run();
    }
}

class Test {

    private int x;

    void foo() {

        synchronized (this){
            System.out.println("Entered");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Exit");
        }
    }
}

class T extends Thread {

    static Test t = new Test();

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Thread started");
        t.foo();
    }

}
```

Output:

Thread started

Entered

Exit

Thread started

Entered

Exit

Comment: You should use start() method instead of run() to start a Thread.

Comment: You handled `InterruptedException` improperly; in fact, you didn't handle it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run these as separate threads, you need to call the [`Thread.start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--) method.

Instead, you're calling the `run()` method directly. The two calls will execute in the same thread as the caller.

As an aside, usually you can just subclass [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) rather than Thread. Then you can choose to pass your Runnable to the Thread(Runnable) constructor -- or to an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).